# File synchronization Visual Studio 2015 error

Tags: vb.net, ftp, synchronization

I'm coming back to you because I still have a problem in my source code, I'll remind you that I'm trying to do an FTP synchronization from the following source that I copied
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5qSxrbrf9I

Error:

> BC31143   La méthode 'Private Sub File_Downloaded(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)' n'a pas de signature compatible avec le délégué 'Delegate Sub DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)'.
>   Erreur    BC30311 Impossible de convertir une valeur de type 'FtpWebResponse' en 'FtpWebRequest'.
>   Erreur  BC30456 'GetResponseStream' n'est pas un membre de 'FtpWebRequest'.

**FTPManager.vb (Class)**

```html
Public Class FTPManager
    Private Shared ConfigFile As String =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) & "\config.txt"

    Public Shared Folder As String = "Client_Pokemonia"
    Public Shared ServerRootPatch As String
    Public Shared User As String
    Public Shared PW As String

    Public Shared Sub loadConfig()
        If IO.File.Exists(ConfigFile) Then
            Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(ConfigFile)
            ServerRootPatch = lines(0)
            User = lines(1)
            PW = lines(2)

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form1.vb**

```html
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Private LocalPath As String = "Downloadedfiles"
    Private missingFiles As New List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FTPManager.loadConfig()
        createLocalFolderIfNotExistes()
        btnRefresh.performClick()
    End Sub
    Private Sub createLocalFolderIfNotExistes()
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(LocalPath) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalPath)
    End Sub
Private Sub getLocalFiles()
        dgvLocal.Rows.clear
        Dim files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(LocalPath)
        If files.Count > 0 Then
            For Each f In files
                Me.dgvLocal.Rows.Add(f.Split("\c").Last())
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub getFTPFiles()
        dgvFTP.Rows.Clear()
        missingFiles.Clear()
        Dim request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPManager.ServerRootPatch)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTPManager.User, FTPManager.PW)
        Dim response As FtpWebRequest = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
        Using myReader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Do Until Not myReader.EndOfStream
                Dim file = myReader.ReadLine()
                Me.dgvFTP.Rows.Add(file)
                If Not IO.File.Exists(LocalPath & "\" & file) Then
                    dgvFTP.Rows(dgvFTP.Rows.Count - 1).defaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192)
                    missingFiles.Add(file)
                Else : dgvFTP.Rows(dgvFTP.Rows.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192)
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
        '      If Not btnRefresh Then
        '     btnRefresh.Enabled = False
        '  Await Task.Delay(2000)
        '   getLocalFiles()
        '  getFTPFiles()
        '   btnSync.Enabled = True
        '  Else : MessageBox.Show("please wait")

        '  End If
        dgvFTP.ClearSelection()
        dgvLocal.ClearSelection()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnSync_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSync.Click
        If missingFiles.Count > 0 Then
            Donwload_File(New Uri(FTPManager.ServerRootPatch & FTPManager.Folder & "/" & missingFiles(0)))
        Else : MessageBox.Show("No files to downlaod")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Donwload_File(URI As Uri)
        Dim filename = URI.ToString().Split("/c").Last()
        prgb.Value = 0
        'lblFile.text = filename
        Using wc As New WebClient
            wc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTPManager.User, FTPManager.PW)
            AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf File_DLProgressChanged
            AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf File_Downloaded
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(URI, LocalPath & "\" & filename)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub File_DLProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        prgb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub File_Downloaded(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim deletedFile = missingFiles(0)
        missingFiles.RemoveAt(0)

        If missingFiles.Count > 0 Then
            Donwload_File(New Uri(FTPManager.ServerRootPatch & FTPManager.Folder & "/" & missingFiles(0)))
        Else
            btnRefresh.PerformClick()
            MessageBox.Show("niquel")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
Dim response As FtpWebRequest = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
```

read what the error message is telling you and then read that line.  You call `GetResponse` and cast the result as type FtpWeb**Response**, then you try to assign that top a variable of type FtpWeb**Request**.  The error message is telling you that you can't convert an object of one type to the other, which would be required for that assignment to work.

Comment: Good job ! I had not seen my faults at all! Would you have a solution for my latest error?

Gravité Code Description Projet Fichier Ligne État de la suppression
Erreur BC31143 La méthode 'Private Sub File_Downloaded(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)' n'a pas de signature compatible avec le délégué 'Delegate Sub DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)'.

Comment: If you have a new issue then please post a new question with just the information relevant to that issue.  If this answer has solved your current issue, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.  Also, please translate future error message to English.